# How to lower alpha behind overlay with composer?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am currently trying to figure out how to fade the parent screen by reducing it's alpha when a overlay is shown, only to return the alpha to 1 after the overlay goes away.

I can only seem to make it work with the following

> ```
>   function loreButtonTap:tap(e)
>     transition.to(sceneGroup,{
>     alpha= .5,
>     time= 400
>     })
> ```

```
    composer.showOverlay("westerosLore", {
    effect ="fromTop",
    time = 800
    })

    loreTap = display.newRect(_W,_H,_W*2,_H*2);
    display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(loreTap)
    loreTap.alpha = 0;
    loreTap.isHitTestable = true;
    loreTap:addEventListener("tap", loreTap);
    function loreTap:tap(e)
        transition.to(sceneGroup,{
         alpha= 1,
         time= 400
        })
        composer.hideOverlay("slideUp",400);
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)
    end
```

I am doing all of this from inside of the parent window. The problem is if the player rapidly presses the loreButtonTap (spams it fast), it crashes the game claiming that `composer.hideOverlay("slideUp",400);` has become `nil`.

Am I supposed to be hiding the overlay in the overlays lua file? Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to draw a black rectangle in your overlay scene and give it an alpha value. This provides a good illusion of faded parent scene.